# How to get profile pic from Firebase Facebook login in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a website where user is logging to Facebook using Firebase. However, when I try to retrieve profile picture, I am not getting it.

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {

     const uid = user.uid;
     document.querySelector('.user-info > h3').textContent = user.displayName;
     document.querySelector('.user-info > img').src = user.photoURL;

    } else {
    // User is signed out
      }
    });
```

[image: Getting this, instead of profile picture]

Comment: You need to append the access token with the URL. `cons pic = user.photoURL + "?access_token="+accessToken;`

Comment: How, I tried but getting an error. How can I access accessToken in onAuthStateChanged?